# Mostrar dato SQLite en EditText

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tengo una **BD** en `SQLite` y estoy teniendo una complicación a la hora de querer mostrar el valor almacenado. El valor existe, puesto que ya he extraído la **BD** y está. Me surge la duda al momento de querer mostrarlo, esta es mi forma de llamar al dato:

```
public ArrayList mostrarDatosDelPj(String nombrePJ) {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    this.abrirDBLeer();
    String[] campos = new String[]{FlorTablaSqlite.ID_STAT_FLOR, FlorTablaSqlite.NOMBRE_PERSONAJE, FlorTablaSqlite.STAT_PRINC,
            FlorTablaSqlite.STAT_SEC_A, FlorTablaSqlite.STAT_SEC_B, FlorTablaSqlite.STAT_SEC_C, FlorTablaSqlite.STAT_SEC_D};
    String where = FlorTablaSqlite.NOMBRE_PERSONAJE + " IN ('" + nombrePJ + "');";
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(FlorTablaSqlite.TABLA_FLOR, campos, where, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Flor flor = new Flor();
            flor.setId(c.getInt(0));
            flor.setNombrePersonaje(c.getString(1));
            flor.setPrincipal(c.getString(2));
            flor.setSecundarioA(c.getString(3));
            flor.setSecundarioB(c.getString(4));
            flor.setSecundarioC(c.getString(5));
            flor.setSecundarioD(c.getString(6));
            list.add(flor);
        }
    } finally { c.close(); }
    this.cerrarBD();
    return list;
}
```

En mi actividad, trato de mostrarlo a través de la selección de un valor de un `Spinner`:

```
        spPJMisBuilds.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1) {
                DatosProcesosSqlite datosProcesosSqlite = new DatosProcesosSqlite(getApplicationContext());
                florArrayList = datosProcesosSqlite.mostrarDatosDelPj(spPJMisBuilds.getSelectedItem().toString());
                etFlorPrin.setText(florArrayList.get(position).getPrincipal()); //trato de mostrar el dato ya guardado
                guardarFlor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
            }//resto código
```

Y el `LogCat` me marca el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

En la línea:

```
etFlorPrin.setText(florArrayList.get(position).getPrincipal());
```

¿QUé estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Hola Franqo, con que ArrayList llenas el Adapter el spinner? este ArrayList tiene datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me estaba faltando el ciclo for:

```
    DatosProcesosSqlite datosProcesosSqlite = new DatosProcesosSqlite(getApplicationContext());
    //flor
    florArrayList = datosProcesosSqlite.mostrarDatosDelPjFlor(spPJMisBuilds.getSelectedItem().toString());
    for(int i = 0; i < florArrayList.size(); i++){
        if(etFlorPrin.getText().toString()=="" || etFlorPrin.getText().toString()==null || etFlorPrin.equals("")
                || etFlorSecA.getText().toString()=="" || etFlorSecA.getText().toString()==null || etFlorSecA.equals("")
                || etFlorSecB.getText().toString()=="" || etFlorSecB.getText().toString()==null || etFlorSecB.equals("")
                || etFlorSecC.getText().toString()=="" || etFlorSecC.getText().toString()==null || etFlorSecC.equals("")
                || etFlorSecD.getText().toString()=="" || etFlorSecD.getText().toString()==null || etFlorSecD.equals("")){
            limpiarET();
        }else{
            etFlorPrin.setText(florArrayList.get(i).getPrincipal());
            etFlorSecA.setText(florArrayList.get(i).getSecundarioA());
            etFlorSecB.setText(florArrayList.get(i).getSecundarioB());
            etFlorSecC.setText(florArrayList.get(i).getSecundarioC());
            etFlorSecD.setText(florArrayList.get(i).getSecundarioD());
        }
    }
```